# Build an eclipse project from console without ant

Tags: java, console

I got an eclipse project which has more than 10 packages. I need to build it to run in an environment where there is no ant.

Please provide me some support.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javac

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `ant` to run a java program.

Although, you do need a java runtime (JRE).

For that, you can export binaries produced by Eclispe as a `.jar` file.

File->Export->Jar File.

Comment: By that @Alexander says you should do it on a computer on which you have Eclipse. You prepare an executable package with that command. You can distribute this .jar file and anyone having the JRE can run your application using this jar file.

Comment: i know i can run a program with the jar file but it didn't work. I need to build it in that environment

Comment: @small_ticket What specifically did not work?  The problem may be that you are missing some 3rd party `jar` files needed to run your application.  Also, what version of JRE is installed on a target platform?  If you built against 1.6, but target machine has 1.4, then it will not run.  However, you may ask Eclipse to compile it to run under 1.4.

Comment: that was my mistake, jar also worked out. I haven't exported jar file as an executable. Thanks